# iOS Simulator "Now Playing" screen missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I had developed my app for iOS 9+ devices few months back and at that time `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` was working as expected. But recently I updated my XCode also to latest 9.3 and due to some Pods library being updated I had to change the `Deployment Target` to 10.0. Since then the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` stops working and never shows up on lock screen on any Simulator devices.

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
            MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: self.playerItem.title.br2Sp.stripTags,
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: self.playerItem.artist.br2Sp.stripTags,
            MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: player.rate
        ]
```

Any idea what has changed since then?

P.S. By *stops working* I mean that my above code no longer displays the `Now Playing` info on lock screen.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you.  Please add your code and detail what "stops working" means.

Comment: @DavidS. I updated my question

Answer (score 8):

After searching a lot, I finally came to know that iOS Simulator v11.3 does not have support yet for Control Panel and it shows a frosted screen without any controls. I have downloaded iOS Simulator v10.3.1 and its now showing up.

Comment: This is still true for version 12.1 - very annoying.

Comment: 14.x outhere, guess what

Comment: 15.x aaaaand guess what? :))